# Jquery file upload ... freezes more than 100MB # blueimp jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

i wanted to upload bigger files using jquery file upload from blueimp.

it is fine for smaller files but for big files >100mb it doesnt seem to be doing anything.  The progress bar doesnt move it just freezes.

i have done all the suggestions with regards to max file size and max post size in the php.ini

also set the maxfilesize in the script

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    formData: [{ name: 'custom_dir', value: 'mydir' }],
    autoUpload: true,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp4|wmv|mov|Mp4|Wmv|Mov|MP4|WMV|MOV)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 419430400, // 400 MB
```

doesnt work.   does anybody have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

oh problem solved
put in the maxchunksize param   maxChunkSize: 1048576,

```
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    formData: [{ name: 'custom_dir', value: '$f{sessionid}' }],
    autoUpload: true,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\\.|\\/)(mp4|wmv|mov|Mp4|Wmv|Mov|MP4|WMV|MOV)\$/i,
    maxFileSize: 419430400, // 400 MB
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    maxChunkSize: 1048576,
```